# nginx proxy_pass over https_proxy

Tags: nginx, http-proxy, proxypass

I am trying to set up nginx with this config. To access backend.mygreat.server.com I have to go through my corporate proxy, which is myproxy.server.com:80.

Hence, I have added this in /etc/environment

```
https_proxy=myproxy.server.com:80
```

Yet, nginx is unable to reach https://backend.mygreat.server.com:443. I'm seeing 504 as HTTP status in nginx logs.

I could use wget or curl to load the page (goes via corporate proxy)

```
  server {
        listen  443;
        server_name  mygreat.server.com;
        ssl  on;
        ssl_protocols  TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM:EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384:EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256:EECDH+aRSA+SHA384:EECDH+aRSA+SHA256:EECDH:EDH+aRSA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!SEED:!DSS:!CAMELLIA;

        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/mygreat.server.com.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/mygreat.server.com.key;

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.ssl.log;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP  $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header X-Real-Pcol http;

          proxy_intercept_errors on;
          error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;      

          proxy_pass https://backend.mygreat.server.com:443;
        }

        location @handle_redirects {
            set $saved_redirect_location '$upstream_http_location';
            proxy_pass $saved_redirect_location;
        }    
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

**Update :**

Here is the sample error log from nginx

```
2017/10/18 06:55:51 [warn] 34604#34604: *1 upstream server temporarily disabled while connecting to upstream, client: <ip-address>, server: mygreat.server.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://<ip-of-backend>:443/", host: "mygreat.server.com"
```

If I run `curl -v https://backend.mygreat.server.com/` below is the response

```
* About to connect() to proxy corp-proxy.server.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying <some-ip-address>...
* Connected to corp-proxy.server.com (<ip-of-proxy>) port 80 (#0)
* Establish HTTP proxy tunnel to backend.mygreat.server.com:443
> CONNECT backend.mygreat.server.com:443 HTTP/1.1
> Host: backend.mygreat.server.com:443
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established
<
* Proxy replied OK to CONNECT request
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate:
*   subject: CN=backend.mygreat.server.com,OU=Technology Operations,O=MyCompany.,L=San Diego,ST=California,C=US
*   start date: Mar 15 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*   expire date: Mar 15 23:59:59 2020 GMT
*   common name: backend.mygreat.server.com
*   issuer: CN=Symantec Class 3 Secure Server CA - G4,OU=Symantec Trust Network,O=Symantec Corporation,C=US
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: backend.mygreat.server.com
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: openresty/1.11.2.5
< Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2017 14:03:10 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
< Content-Length: 5642
< Connection: keep-alive
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, private
< Expires: 0
< P3P: policyref="http://backend.mygreat.server.com/w3c/p3p.xml" CP="CURa OUR STP UNI INT"
< Content-Language: en
< Set-Cookie: qboeuid=127.0.0.1.1508335390550307; path=/; expires=Thu, 18-Oct-18 14:03:10 GMT; domain=.server.com
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=784529AA39C10C3DB4B0ED0D61CC8F31.c23-pe2ec23uw2apu012031; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: something.blah_blah=testme; Domain=.server.com; Path=/; Secure
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
....
</html>
```

Comment: Run `ps auxe | grep nginx` and see if your environment variable has actually reached the process or not. How are you launching nginx? Using systemd service or some other way?

Comment: @TarunLalwani `ps auxe | grep nginx` shows `https_proxy` being used by `nginx: worker` process. I'm starting nginx using `systemctl start nginx`

Comment: Can post the exact error logs from Nginx?

Comment: Also I notice there is a redirect happening in the proxy_pass backend (`backend.mygreat.server.com`). I've updated my question with error log

Comment: Can you first disable redirect handling and test? remove `error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;`. Handle one issue at a time, first check if the proxy is working or not and then work on getting redirects to work

Comment: @TarunLalwani my corp proxy is working. I have updated my question with output from `curl` when I run it on the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157008/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-arun-avanathan).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So first of all I am not sure if Nginx is suppose to respect `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables. I didn't find any documentation on the same. So I assume your issues is related to nginx not using proxy at a all

So now you have an option to use something which actually uses proxy. This is where `socat` comes to rescue.

### Running socat forwarder

If you have a transparent proxy then run

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork TCP:<proxysever>:<proxyport>
```

And if you have CONNECT proxy then use below

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:8443,reuseaddr,fork PROXY:yourproxy:backendserver:443,proxyport=<yourproxyport>
```

Then in your nginx config use

```
    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header Host-Real-IP  $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-Pcol http;

      proxy_intercept_errors on;
      proxy_set_header Host backend.mygreat.server.com;
      proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8443;
      proxy_redirect https://backend.mygreat.server.com https://mygreat.server.com;
    }
```

You probably want to use Systemd service to launch the socat, so it runs on startup and is handled as a service

Comment: I didn't use `proxy_redirect` but your suggestion worked beautifully. Thanks a lot for your help and tips. I learnt quite a bit.

Comment: Here is the ticket opened on nginx - https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1399#ticket

Comment: Depending on the use case you may also need to include the Host in the SNI extension for the request going to socat.

Comment: Thanks.  Another tool which doesn't respect http_proxy is ssh when you use -R for port forwarding.  The socat trick worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this response; unfortunately, it does not support SSL/TLS to the CONNECT proxy server (aka HTTPS proxy), any idea how to achieve it ?

Comment: @FlorentThiery were you able to find a way to go through SSL/TLS. I am getting 502 with above solution.

Comment: Although i did not try, it should be possible to chain 2 socat instances (we eventually gave up because we did not want to depend on it)

Answer (score 0):

Nginx's proxy_pass does not support `https` proxy.
`http` proxy can be supported, but the request url only supports `http`.

**this is a example**:

```
server {
    listen       8880;
    server_name  localhost;
    location / {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ "://developer.android.com$1";
        rewrite ^(.*)$ "http$1" break;

        proxy_set_header Proxy-Connection Keep-Alive;
        proxy_set_header Host developer.android.com;

        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1080;
        proxy_redirect ~^https?://developer\.android\.com(.*)$ http://$host:8080$1;
    }
}
```

see: https://serverfault.com/a/683955/418613

Comment: It doesn't? Can you tell me what all these Nginx directives do then? `proxy_ssl_certificate` `proxy_ssl_certificate_key` `proxy_ssl_ciphers` `proxy_ssl_crl` `proxy_ssl_name` `proxy_ssl_password_file` `proxy_ssl_protocols` `proxy_ssl_server_name` `proxy_ssl_session_reuse` `proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate` `proxy_ssl_verify` `proxy_ssl_verify_depth`

Comment: I did not understand this as a complete answer and also not the linked answer alone, but reading also the question helped: https://serverfault.com/q/583743/149716